# php windows server lock the client pc

Tags: php, sockets

Im trying to create an internet usage control system for my thesis. When the client pc reaches the maximum of hours per day, that pc should be automatically lock. Can someone please help me. Im using php. Thanks!

Comment: _"Can someone please help me."_ - Help you with what? Your question is way too broad and will need to be narrowed down to a specific problem. Please give [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) a read.

Comment: I am pretty sure PHP is not the best choice for something like that.